# How to keep track of Firebase Task after Activity restart?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, task

I have code in a `Fragment` like the following.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("amazing/spiderman");

Map<String, Object> updatesMap = new HashMap<>();
updatesMap.put("name", "Peter Parker");
updatesMap.put("girlFriend", "Mary Jane");

Task<Void> task = databaseReference.updateChildren(updatesMap);
task.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
        {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                // Do something awesome
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, if the device orientation changes right after starting the `Task`, the `Task` gets destroyed (as expected) and the `OnCompleteListener` never gets called. So I have no clue about whether the Task completed successfully or failed after the `Activity` gets restarted.

Does the Firebase team suggest any best practice to follow in this case? My search didn't find any concrete suggestions.

There are a number of possible solutions in my mind including using a retained `Fragment` to track state of the `Task`. Which version of `addOnCompleteListener` should I use if I move the `Task` in a retained `Fragment`, keeping in mind that the `Activity` gets destroyed but the `Fragment` doesn't?

Comment: You could separate the firebase logic from the UI layer(activities, fragments etc.) and handle the destroying of listeners on your own.

Comment: A clarification: You are using the form of `addOnCompleteListener()` that accepts an Activity as the first argument.  That causes the listener to be removed when the activity's `onStop()` is called.  That is why the listener is not called after orientation change.  I don't think the "task gets destroyed".  If you used the form of `addOnCompleteListener()` that leaves the listener attached, I believe `onComplete()` would get called when the task completes.  This doesn't answer your question, because this gives you the completion status, but in a dead Activity instance, so you can't update UI.

Comment: You should take a look at the new [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) class, and [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090) describing its use.